# Show data on android desktop with SL4A Python (example)

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I'd like to know how can I show simple and short data (eg: temperature data from a running script) in Android desktop using SL4A. My script gets temperature data from a web, and I tried showing it via notify, via toast and via dialogs, but I´d like it to remain accesible on the screen.
I undestand that webview is an option but I can´t write the xml code for a simple text box, as I undestand I should. 
Is this right? Where could I get a (very) simple code example in xml to show text on screen (not full screen)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just re-read your question there are a few examples of full screen webviews however as far as I understand it webview is kind of an all or nothing deal. If you want to us Xml look into the [Fullscreenwrapper2](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/wiki/fullscreenwrapper2) as it allows you to use similar xml layouts to native java apps, from there you can look for examples of xml layouts and modify to fit.

Do you want a widget or just a dialog box? if you just want a dialog box you can just use a dialogCreateAlert

```
import android

droid = android.Android()

title=("Your Tittle")
content=("Your content")

droid.dialogCreateAlert(title, content)
droid.dialogShow()
```

However if you want it on a widget the simplest soloution I have found is to use a [minimalistic text widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.devmil.minimaltext) you can pass the data either through tasker or directly using a local intent.

Through Tasker:

```
import android, time

droid = android.Android()
class Task():
    SET_VARIABLE = 547
    def new_task(self):
        self.action_cnt = 0
        self.extras = {'version_number': '1.0', 'task_name': 'task' + str(time.time()), 'task_priority': 9 }
    def set_var(self, varname, value):
        self.action_cnt += 1
        self.extras['action' + str(self.action_cnt)] = {'action': self.SET_VARIABLE, 'arg:1': varname, 'arg:2': value, 'arg:3': False, 'arg:4': False, 'arg:5': False}
    def run_task(self):
        taskIntent = droid.makeIntent('net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK', None, None, self.extras).result
        droid.sendBroadcastIntent(taskIntent)
    def set_var_now(self, varname, value):
        self.new_task()
        self.set_var(varname, value)
        self.run_task()

t = Task()
t.set_var_now("%Var", "Your variable value")
```

Directly via a Local intent (You select this in MT by using a Local variable field):

```
import android

droid = android.Android()

activity = 'com.twofortyfouram.locale.intent.action.FIRE_SETTING'
extras = {}
extras['de.devmil.minimaltext.locale.extras.VAR_NAME'] = 'Your Variable name'
extras['de.devmil.minimaltext.locale.extras.VAR_TEXT'] = 'Your Variable content'

packagename =  'de.devmil.minimaltext'
classname = 'de.devmil.minimaltext.locale.LocaleFireReceiver'

intent = droid.makeIntent(activity, None, None, extras, None, packagename, classname).result

droid.sendBroadcastIntent(intent)
```